# Mysql on docker /bin/bash: cannot execute binary file

Tags: docker, macos

I'm trying to run the mysql container with docker on an M2 Macbook with

```
docker run --platform linux/amd64 mysql:5.7
```

but it exits with

```
/bin/bash: /bin/bash: cannot execute binary file
```

The strange thing is this same command works perfectly fine on my M1 Macbook. I've attempted to uninstall docker but it hasn't helped. What could be causing this issue?

Comment: What if you override the mysql:5.7 entrypoint like so `docker run --platform linux/amd64 --entrypoint "/usr/bin/tail" mysql:5.7 -f /dev/null`, does the container start?

Comment: @MartinTovmassian Yeah that does seem to start the container and output some random data.

Comment: Looks like I can run a few of the commands like this, but bash isn't working for some reason.

Comment: Ok now connect to the container and try to run `bash /entrypoint.sh mysqld`. Do you get the same error?

Comment: How would I connect to it? The way I'd normally do it won't work with bash not working.

Comment: Could you try `docker exec -it <CONTAINER_ID> /bin/bash`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257286/discussion-between-martin-tovmassian-and-qwertie).

Answer (score 0):

This issue went away after rebooting macos. Before then I had also installed xcode but I'm not sure if this had any impact.